Blaze Persistance fetching related entities with pagination in single query
I'm using Spring Boot and Blaze Persistance.
While I know that probably the best solution for pagination and fetching is something like  this:
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<AnimalDto> findAll(Pageable pageable, SpecSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    CriteriaBuil

der<String> idCb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, String.class)
            .from(Animal.class, "a")
            .select("a.id")
            .orderByAsc("a.id")
            .setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

List<String> ids = idCb.getResultList();
Long totalCount = idCb.getCountQuery().getSingleResult();

// Then fetch full entities with relations using the IDs
CriteriaBuilder<Animal> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Animal.class)
        .from(Animal.class, "a")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).behaviors")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).species")
        .where("a.id").in(ids)
        .orderByAsc("a.id");

List<Animal> animals = cb.getResultList();

List<AnimalDto> dtos = animals.stream()
        .map(animal -> animalOperations.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).mapToDto(animal))
        .toList();

return new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, totalCount);

but i want to reduce db calls and have something like this:
CriteriaBuilder<Animal> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Animal.class)
            .distinct()
            .from(Animal.class, "animal")
            .leftJoin("TREAT(animal AS Pet).behaviors", "behav")    
            .leftJoin("TREAT(animal AS Pet).species", "spec")       
            .fetch("behav")                                         
            .fetch("spec")
            .setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    List<Animal> animals = cb.getResultList();
    Long totalCount = cb.getCountQuery().getSingleResult();

    List<AnimalDto> dtos = animals.stream()
            .map(animal -> animalOperations.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).mapToDto(animal))
            .toList();

    return new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, totalCount);

but after this i got:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate column name...

I have also tried using PaginatedCriteriaBuilder from Blaze Persistence, but I encountered two issues:
-The pagination shows incorrect numbers for total elements etc.
-Duplicate records are appearing in the results
CriteriaBuilder<Animal> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Animal.class)
        .from(Animal.class, "a")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).behaviors")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).species")
        .orderByAsc("a.id");

List<Animal> animals = cb
        .page(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize())
        .withCountQuery(false)
        .getResultList();

CriteriaBuilder<Long> countCb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Long.class)
        .from(Animal.class, "a")
        .select("COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)");

Long totalCount = countCb.getSingleResult();

List<AnimalDto> dtos = animals.stream()
        .map(animal -> animalOperations.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).mapToDto(animal))
        .toList();

return new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, totalCount);

The Ideal solution would be:

SINGLE db query with pagination and all fetched data.
At most, I would accept 2 queries.

Additional context:
-Animal is a base class.
-Pet inherit from Animal.
-Everything is in single table inheritance.
Can you help me achieve this optimization?

You should read the documentation about how pagination with Blaze-Persistence works under the hood.
The easiest solution, if you don't like the count query being embedded in the main query, is to disable count query inlining.
CriteriaBuilder<Animal> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Animal.class)
        .from(Animal.class, "a")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).behaviors")
        .fetch("TREAT(a AS Pet).species")
        .orderByAsc("a.id");

PagedList<Animal> animals = cb
        .page(pageable.getOffset(), pageable.getPageSize())
        .withInlineCountQuery(false)
        .getResultList();

Long totalCount = animals.getTotalSize();

List<AnimalDto> dtos = animals.stream()
        .map(animal -> animalOperations.get(animal.getClass().getSimpleName()).mapToDto(animal))
        .toList();

return new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, totalCount);


I get duplicated Pet records and  when  tried "?page=3"  result will be :
pageable": {
"pageNumber": 3,
"pageSize": 10,
"sort": {
"empty": true,
"sorted": false,
"unsorted": true
},
"offset": 30,
"paged": true,
"unpaged": false
},
"last": true,
"totalElements": 35,
"totalPages": 4,
"size": 10,
"number": 3,
"sort": {
"empty": true,
"sorted": false,
"unsorted": true
},
"numberOfElements": 5,

Not sure what that output means exactly, but I had a typo in the sample code. You should rather use getOffset() instead of getPageNumber() when passing arguments to page(). If you need further assistance, it would be best if you ask on GitHub: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence

Your solution works fine when .withInlineCountQuery(false) is used - everything works properly. However, when .withInlineCountQuery(true) is used, entities with more than one relation are duplicated in the results.

That would be a bug then. I would appreciate if you could create an issue on GitHub with a reproducer: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/new
